# MYSQL Binary in Where Clause

Tags: mysql

I have table mysql name  **customer** . And have 1 record ***customer.mypage_login_id = 'hoangthien.lp+45@gmail.com'*** .

When i use query :

```
SELECT mypage_login_id , customer.*
FROM (`customer`)
WHERE mypage_login_id = BINARY 'Hoangthien.lp+45@gmail.com'
AND `disable` =  0;
```

Result : no row found

But when i use query :

```
SELECT mypage_login_id , customer.*
FROM (`customer`)
WHERE mypage_login_id = 'Hoangthien.lp+45@gmail.com'
AND mypage_login_id = BINARY 'Hoangthien.lp+45@gmail.com'
AND `disable` =  0;
```

Result : 1 row found .
Why ?
I using Mysql 5.7

Comment: What is the field `my_login_id` type in the table?

Comment: Type is varchar(128)

Answer (score 0):

The binary keyword can be used after WHERE clause to compare a value with exact case sensitive match.

In your case, the value of `mypage_login_id` in your first query (`Hoangthien.lp+45@gmail.com`) doesn't match your record in your table `hoangthien.lp+45@gmail.com`.

And in your second query, your first WHERE condition isn't case sensitive, that's why that works.

Comment: in my second query , still has the condition mypage_login_id = BINARY 'Hoangthien.lp+45@gmail.com'

Comment: Indeed you're right, I tried to reproduce but I face a syntax error on the usage of BINARY as a keyword before the string value, so that's weird that it's even working for you

Answer (score 0):

You do not need BINARY data type specificator - your data is textual.

You may specify binary collation (like `WHERE mypage_login_id = 'Hoangthien.lp+45@gmail.com' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`) if you want to apply binary compare. This is more correct.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd012fcf1e61c432fef269fc9c6c7ea0

PS. Do not enclose the table name into the parenthesis.